# Dealing with subvectors in costant time

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, vector

I'm implementing an algorithm and I need to be really efficient. My algorithm works on a set of equal and constant size vectors of bools, and I would like to keep them consecutive in memory to avoid cache misses. Since it's used a lot of time, my solution at the moment is to concatenate all the vectors in the set in a unique bigger vector, before running the algorithm. This should make all the vectors consecutive in the memory, but give me another problem: I can't access anymore a  single vector that is in the set. Of course, I can use

```
vector<bool>(concatenation.begin()+i, concatenation.end()+i+vector_size)
```

but this would make a copy of the data, vanishing my original objective of optimizing performance. Ideally, I would like to have a function that returns me a `const vector<vector_type>&` of the subvector, since I only need to read the content and not modify it during the algorithm execution.

I'm open also to completely different solutions to do it, but if it is possible I would like to avoid using the iterators.

I've also to say that the size of the vectors of bools is known at compile-time, so maybe an `array` would work, but I've read that they shouldn't be used because of they are a  wrapper to unsafe C arrays.

Comment: FWIW, a `vector<bool>` packs it "elements" together and behaves as a bitset.  That bit manipulation is going to come with a run time cost.  If you can spare the space, you might be better off using something else that doesn't compress the information.  Also, `std::array` is the way to go if you know what the size will be at compile time.  It also doesn't pack like vector does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only need to read the content and not modify it during the algorithm execution

Well first off you can't use `vector<bool>` like this because it acts as a bit field so you can't "extract" sequences of it. Use `vector<char>` instead.

That said, you can easily get a pointer to your data, like:

```
char *array = concatenation.data() + i;
// use it as a normal array, for example: array[0]
```

> I've read that [std::array] shouldn't be used because of they are a wrapper to unsafe C arrays

What do you think `std::vector` is? It's all arrays, all the way down!